# passing string formatter as argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a function called showMessage which displays the alert message dialog. This function takes string as parameter and shows this string as a message of dialog. At start I wanted the way to pass string and also sting formatter along with it, something like this:

```
[self showMessageDialog:@"Hello %@", self.studentName];
```

As you can see what I want to achieve. So I made my function signature something like this:

```
- (void) showMessageDialog:(NSString *)message, ...{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" 
                                                message:message 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
```

With this I can pass multiple formatters(i mean argument which will go on placeholders) during function call, but I am missing something which doesn't allow me to show my formatter arguments on message. I mean I always get this message on message dialog: "Hello %@".

I know I have missed something like I have made the way to pass the multiple arguments to function call but I think i haven't made it how to place those arguments on their placeholders.

Note: I want to make function work like NSLog, way we call NSLog and pass arguments.

Comment: You need to use your format string in a call to `stringWithFormat`, then pass that result to the `message` parm of the init statement.

Comment: Hi thanks. I wanted to make function like How NSLog works, i mean we dont have to use stringWithFormat on them right ?.

Comment: Just how *did* you think that NSLog works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is building a vararg function. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html) on how to do it.

Specifically, as far as I understand you will be also be interested in how you can pass your variable argument list from your method to another function taking a variable argument list (say that you want to call `sprintf` from your `showMessageDialog:`). This is explained [here](http://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11c.html). Actually, this is easily done (e.g., with NSLog):

```
- (void) showMessageDialog:(NSString *)message, ... {

    va_list argp;

    va_start(argp, msg);
    NSLog(msg, argp);
    va_end(argp);

}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. So i have to implement in C ?

Comment: you can have a vararg ObjC method, but the underlying mechanism is the old C vararg mechanism. See also my edit. In the end, C is a subset of ObjC, you can use C wherever you want in ObjC...